# Graphic design feeds to follow

Tags: resource-recommendations

What are some Graphic Design resources online that regularly post content addressing history, trends and changes in- or explaining principles of Graphic Design?

In the best case they offer a feed to follow updates.

Answer (score 3):

[GD USA](http://www.gdusa.com/) is a good read. I dont know about "history" but what is trending I usually read [Adobe's Magazine](http://layersmagazine.com/) for some good tutorials and concepts with Adobe software.

For my area there are sign magazines like [Signs of The Times](http://www.signweb.com/). My favorite right now for design is a UK based company called [Imagine Publishing](http://www.imagine-publishing.co.uk/).

There magazines, specially the web designer mags, are high in the US because they are based in the UK but their information and magazines are far worth it.  If you sign up for their digital edition you can get the back issues but I'm old fashioned and like a printed magazine at times.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't read it in a while, but [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/) has a lot of good content.

[A List Apart](http://alistapart.com/) is just for web design.